# Running sum on a column conditional on value

Tags: r, vector, apply, cumulative-sum

I have a vector of binary variables which state whether a product is on promotion in the period.  I'm trying to work out how to calculate the duration of each promotion and the duration between promotions.

```
promo.flag = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0))
```

So in other words: if `promo.flag` is same as previous period then `running.total + 1`, else `running.total` is reset to 1

I've tried playing with apply functions and cumsum but can't manage to get the conditional reset of running total working :-(

The output I need is:

```
promo.flag =  c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0)
rolling.sum = c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,0)
```

Can anybody shed any light on how to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need run length encoding (via the `rle` command in base R).

```
unlist(sapply(rle(promo.flag)$lengths,seq))
```

Gives you a vector `1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 1`.  Not sure what you're going for with the zero at the end, but I assume it's a terminal condition and easy to change after the fact.

This works because `rle()` returns a list of two, one of which is named `lengths` and contains a compact sequence of how many times each is repeated.  Then `seq` when fed a single integer gives you a sequence from 1 to that number.  Then apply repeatedly calls `seq` with the single numbers in `rle()$lengths`, generating a list of the mini sequences.  `unlist` then turns that list into a vector.

Comment: Many thanks, that's fixed it and given me further functions to learn!!

Excellent, prompt response!

Comment: No problem.  As it turns out, I just found a use for this very function :-).  Also take a look at the `rollapply` family of functions in the `zoo` library, which are more powerful but at the price of a fixed window size (there may be a way to change it; I'm not super familiar with them).

Comment: P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow! We hope you'll stick around the [r] tag.