# data frame cumulative run length encoding in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame containing values relating to observations, 1 or 0. I want to count the continual occurrences of 1, resetting at 0. The run length encoding function (`rle`) seems like it would do the work but I can't work out getting the data into the desired format. I want to try doing this without writing a custom function. In the data below, I have observation in a data frame, then I want to derive the "continual" column and write back to the dataframe. This link was a [good start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249338/running-sum-on-a-column-conditional-on-value/9249411).

```
observation continual 
          0         0
          0         0
          0         0
          1         1
          1         2
          1         3
          1         4
          1         5
          1         6
          1         7
          1         8
          1         9
          1        10
          1        11
          1        12
          0         0
          0         0
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this pretty easily in a couple of steps:

```
x <- rle(mydf$observation)       ## run rle on the relevant column
new <- sequence(x$lengths)       ## create a sequence of the lengths values
new[mydf$observation == 0] <- 0  ## replace relevant values with zero
new
#  [1]  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  0  0
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [the devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) you could try

```
library(data.table) ## v >= 1.9.5
setDT(df)[, continual := seq_len(.N) * observation, by = rleid(observation)]
```

Comment: This will not reset when it reaches 0.

Comment: @Frank, Steve is right, your edit is invalid. This is one of the greatest mysteries on how `.I` actually works.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably a better way, but:

```
g <- c(0,cumsum(abs(diff(df$obs))))
df$continual <- ave(g,g,FUN=seq_along)
df$continual[df$obs==0] <- 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply adapting the accepted answer from the question you linked:

```
unlist(mapply(function(x, y) seq(x)*y, rle(df$obs)$lengths, rle(df$obs)$values))
# [1]  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple base `R` one liner, using the fact observation contains only `0` and `1` , coupled with a vectorized operation:

```
transform(df, continual=ifelse(observation, cumsum(observation), observation))

#   observation continual
#1            0         0
#2            0         0
#3            0         0
#4            1         1
#5            1         2
#6            1         3
#7            1         4
#8            1         5
#9            1         6
#10           1         7
#11           1         8
#12           1         9
#13           1        10
#14           1        11
#15           1        12
#16           0         0
#17           0         0
```

Comment: Does this work if there are additional runs of ones? It's sort of vague, but I'm thinking of " I want to count the continual occurrences of 1, resetting at 0"

Comment: True! I would do `sequence(rle(df1$observation)$lengths)` but that's exactly similar to @Aranda except I put the code in a more compact way.

Comment: You can do `sequence(rle(df1$observation)$lengths) * df1$observation` to keep zeros at zero.